# Reading from a stream in Windows Phone7

Tags: windows-phone-7, stream

I am working with Windows Phone SDK 7 and am trying to implement the download of an image file.  I cannot use the standard BitmapImage object because my server uses forms authentication cookies and I as far as I can tell, there is no way to pass the browser control or the BitmapImage object a cookie container... (btw. if there is a way to do that, I'd like to know as well - it will make my code much simpler!).

Regardless, what I am trying to do should be possible - I get a response stream and now I need to read the image data from it.

Howerver

```
    _clientData.BeginRead(_buffer, _currentPosition, _buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), null);
```

Returns the error:

```
    Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
    Parameter name: count
       at MS.Internal.InternalNetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count,         AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at TestCode.ItemViewModel.ReadImageByChunks()
       at TestCode.ItemViewModel.ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
       at MS.Internal.InternalNetworkStream.StreamAsyncResult.Complete(Int32 bytesProcessed,         Boolean synchronously, Exception error)
       at MS.Internal.InternalNetworkStream.ReadOperation(Object state)
       at MS.Internal.InternalNetworkStream.BeginRead(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count,         AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
       at TestCode.ItemViewModel.ReadImageByChunks()
       at TestCode.ItemViewModel.<>c__DisplayClassb.<LoadImageFromServer>b__a(IAsyncResult rspAR)
       at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.<>c__DisplayClassa.<InvokeGetResponseCallback>b__8(Object state2)
       at System.Threading.ThreadPool.WorkItem.doWork(Object o)
       at System.Threading.Timer.ring()
```

This does not happen the first time through the code (when clientData.Position==0).  The second time through it always is thrown (when clientData.Position==4096).

count is _buffer.Length.

```
    private void ReadImageByChunks()
    {
        try
        {
            _clientData.BeginRead(_buffer, _currentPosition, _buffer.Length, new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), null);

        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            int i = 1; 
        }
    }

    private void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            int bytesRead = _clientData.EndRead(ar);

            if (bytesRead > 0)
            {
                _imageStream.Write(_buffer, _currentPosition, bytesRead);
                _currentPosition = _currentPosition + bytesRead;
            }

            if (bytesRead == _buffer.Length)
                ReadImageByChunks();
            else
            {
                //do stuff 
            }
        }
        catch (Exception error)
        {
            int i = 1;
        }
    }
```

I have re-written this code several times now based on my own intuition and on code I have found on the Internet (but none specific to Windows Phone 7).  The version above is modeled on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784878/continuously-reading-from-a-stream) post. But no luck so far.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't pass an index into BeginRead, as it refers to the index of the *buffer* to start writing to. You're currently asking out to write to the buffer outsider its bounds.

Replace _currentPosition with 0 and it should fix the problem. In fact, you don't need to track _currentPosition at all, since streams keep their own state.

Comment: Thanks Richard - this solved the problem! Unfortunately I don't have the required points to vote for your Answer :(.

Comment: @user917153 you posted that comment as a new, anonymous, user. If you log back in as the user that posted the question (LWP) you can mark it as "the answer". You'll still be logged in if you use the same computer/browser as before :)